# Unknown column 'xyz' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysql-error-1054

I created a user defined sql query that doesn't work.  Users are supposed to be able to enter search strings in an input field, submit then see the results of their search but everytime I enter a search for something that I know is in the database I get the unknown column "x" in "where clause" error message.

Would you please help me fix the problem?  Here's the code that i wrote for it so far...

```
...
mysql_select_db("mydb", $c);
$search = $_POST['search'];

$rslt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE 'mycolumn' RLIKE $search");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rslt))
  {
  echo $row['myrow'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

if (!$row)
  {
  die('uh oh: ' . mysql_error());
  }

?>
```

Comment: Try using backticks rather than quotes when "wrapping" table or column names, but you should quote strings such as $search

Comment: So do you have a column named mycolumn in there? And a table named mytable?

Answer (score 4):

Change the code to this:
1) Convert quotes to backticks around column name.
2) Surround $search with single qoutes to make it a string.

```
 $rslt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `mycolumn` RLIKE '{$search}'");
```

Comment: [Backticks are unnecessary unless the column name is also a reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: @OMG Ponies, yes but we do not know whether in his code mycolumn is a reserved name or not. So, it's always safe to follow this practice.

Answer (score 1):

This helps for sure
just change the variable $search to be read as a string i.e `$search`
so it will be like this

```
$rslt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn RLIKE '$search'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a few about security and performance.

It is unsafe to put user input (any GET, POST or cookie data) directly into the SQL query. This is a serious security issue called [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). To avoid it, use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function.

Also, `SELECT * FROM mytable ...` is not a good practice. It is recommended to explicitly list all the columns needed even if they all are:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM mytable ...
```